# super class method and subclass method

Tags: java, oop

Please help me about this code,thx!

```
class Parent {
    int num = 4;

    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo() of Parent");
    }

    static protected void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar() of Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int num = 5;

    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo() of Child");
    }

    static protected void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar() of Child");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent f1 = new Parent();
        System.out.println(f1.num);

        Parent f2 = new Child();
        System.out.println(f2.num);

        Child c = new Child();
        System.out.println(c.num);

        f1.foo();
        f2.foo();
        c.foo();

        f1.bar();
        f2.bar();
        c.bar();
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
4
4
5
foo() of Parent
foo() of Child
foo() of Child
bar() of Parent
bar() of Parent
bar() of Child
```

Could you tell me if Person f2=new Child() is polymorphism?If so,why the output of 'f2.num' is 4,but 'f2.foo()' is 'foo() of Child'.
I think it has to do with the super class's static bar().Please tell me the principle,thanks very much.

Comment: this sounds like you're asking for an answer to your school work, I could be wrong but if so that's not really what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Person f2=new Child()` is a **Runtime Polymorphism**. And you are absolutely correct for the output of `f2.num'` is **4**,but `f2.foo()` is `foo() of Child`. As the static member is inherited to the subclass but with some restrictions which are:

- You can override them
- If you redefined a method in the subclass then the inherited method (`bar()`) of the parent class get hidden

Hence when you are creating the object `f2` with the reference of `Parent class` the normal procedure **runtime polymorphism** is happening (binding child object with parent) but as you have redefined the `bar()` method, the parent method gets hidden and the child class `bar()` method is mapped to this statement `f2.bar()`